# Tupled method for case class having a type parameter

Tags: scala, case-class

When having a case class with a type parameter, I don't see how I can call the `tupled` method. It seems to be find with `apply` and `unapply`.

```
scala> case class Foo[T](x:T, y:T)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo.apply[Int] _
res1: (Int, Int) => Foo[Int] = <function2>

scala> Foo.unapply[Int] _
res2: Foo[Int] => Option[(Int, Int)] = <function1>

scala> Foo.tupled[Int] _
<console>:10: error: value tupled is not a member of object Foo
              Foo.tupled[Int] _
              ^
```

Any idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### tl;dr

Companion objects of case classes cannot extend `FunctionN` (which defines `tupled`, with `N` >= 2) when they have type parameters. Use

```
(Foo[Int] _).tupled
```

---

### discussion

When you have a vanilla class such as

```
case class Bar(x: Int, y: Int)
```

its constructor is effectively a `Function2[Int, Int, Bar]`, hence when the compiler generates the companion object `Bar` it can conveniently make it extend `Function2`.

The generated code will then be

```
class Bar extends AnyRef with Product with Serializable { ... }
object Bar extends Function2[Int, Int, Bar] with Serializable { ... }
```

Now consider

```
case class Foo[T](x: T, y: T)
```

If you try to apply the same trick, you'll find yourself in trouble very soon:

```
// this can't compile, what's T?
object Foo extends Function2[T, T, Bar] with Serializable { ... }
```

Since `T` is unknown, the compiler can't make `Foo` a subclass of `Function2` and it can't do much better than make it extend `AnyRef`:

```
class Foo[T] extends AnyRef with Product with Serializable { ... }
object Foo extends AnyRef with Serializable { ... }
```

---

Here's a quick proof of what discussed above (using `scala -Xprint:typer`):

```
scala> case class Bar(x: Int, y: Int)
...
<synthetic> object Bar extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2[Int,Int,Bar] with Serializable {
...

scala> case class Foo[T](x: T, y: T)
...
<synthetic> object Foo extends AnyRef with Serializable {
...
```

---

To wrap it up, when you have type parameters, you have to obtain a `Function2` first

```
val f: Function2[Int, Int, Foo] = Foo[Int] _
```

and then you can call `tupled` on it

```
f.tupled // ((Int, Int)) => Foo[Int]
```