# Succinct way to go from List[Any] to a specific case class

Tags: scala

I've got a `List[Any]` that looks like:

```
val a: List[Any] = List(1, "a", "b", 2.0)
```

I also have a `case class` that looks like:

```
case class Data(field1: Int, field2: String, field3: String, field4: Double)
```

I'd like to instantiate a `case class` *Data* with the values from `a` to look like:

```
val d = Data(1, "a", "b", 2.0)
```

I know I can iterate through `a`, but for a large list that seems cumbersome.

Comment: I don't see how iterating through `a` would get you anywhere.

Comment: Slight typo @erip. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you trying to do CSV parsing, by chance?

Comment: @erip I'm trying to parse a Javascript array. {data: [1, "a", "b", 2.0]}

Comment: @jstuartmill Do you control the upstream source? Having a heterogeneous list is pretty abnormal even for JSON.

Comment: I wish I did. This is the first tie I've had to deal with this in all my years manipulating JSON @erip

Comment: Ouch. :( I know that feeling. That's really unfortunate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using shapeless,

```
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3"
```

You can apply the tuple to your case class,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> import syntax.std.traversable._
import syntax.std.traversable._

scala> case class Data(field1: Int, field2: String, field3: String, field4: Double)
defined class Data

scala> val a: List[Any] = List(1, "a", "b", 2.0)
a: List[Any] = List(1, a, b, 2.0)

scala> (Data.apply _) tupled a.toHList[Int::String::String::Double::HNil].get.tupled
res1: Data = Data(1,a,b,2.0)
```

typesafe way to apply tuple on data class,

```
scala> a.toHList[Int::String::String::Double::HNil].map(_.tupled).map(t => (Data.apply _) tupled t)
res2: Option[Data] = Some(Data(1,a,b,2.0))
```

Comment: This answer is fine, but the unchecked `.get` should give you pause.

Comment: I did `.get` because I'm confident there is value. But sure you can `.map` on it instead. Updated. Thank you.

Comment: I was a bit surprised to find that this works: `.map(Data.apply _ tupled _.tupled)`

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this in a type-safe way. Lists' lengths aren't known until runtime, so there's no way to ensure that `a.length` == `Data#productArity` (see? we're comparing a field of an instance to a field of a type).

You should think about how to not use a `List` to represent your data in the first place.

If you could represent your data as a tuple, you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290955/instantiating-a-case-class-from-a-list-of-parameters) as inspiration, but there be dragons: tuples are nearly as dubious as lists here. Try to instantiate your `case class` directly.